# need help splitting enumerated lists across columns to denote different execution paths.

Tags: lists, columns

I would like to be able to split lists such that there may be multiple paths that get to multiple ends, like the example below. Is there a clean way to do this or something similar?

```
    1. i have a tail
    2. i have feet
       (a) this is a place holder
       (b) so is this
    3. i have a nose
    4. i have fur                  4. i have scales
       (a) xyz                         (a) element yo
       (b) qrs
    5. i am a cat                  5. i can change color
                                   6. i am a lizard
    7. i am an animal
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This would be straightforward using something like tikz.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package. The code below defines a `branch` environment for dealing with your items when they split into two (or more) branches. Inside this environment you can use `\newleaf` to finish one leaf and start the next. This will automatically take care of the `\item` numbers for you.

This is what the code produces:

[image]

...and here is the actual code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns
\makeatletter
\newcount\branch@start% as \setcounter isn't global
\newcount\branch@end
\newenvironment{branch}[1][2]{\begin{multicols}{#1}%
  \branch@start\c@enumi% save value of enumi for subsequent leaves
  \branch@end\c@enumi%   need to keep track of largest enumi in all leaves
  }{%set enumi to largest value in the leaves and close multicols
  \ifnum\c@enumi<\branch@end%
    \global\c@enumi\branch@end% we NEED this to take effect globally
  \fi%
\end{multicols}}
\newcommand\newleaf{%
  \columnbreak%
  \ifnum\c@enumi>\branch@end%
    \global\branch@end\c@enumi%
  \fi%
  \setcounter{enumi}{\branch@start}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{enumerate}
  \item i have a tail
  \item i have feet
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item  this is a place holder
    \item  so is this
  \end{enumerate}
  \item i have a nose
  \begin{branch}
    \item i have fur
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item xyz
      \item qrs
    \end{enumerate}
   \newleaf
     \item i have scales
     \begin{enumerate}
       \item element yo
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{branch}
  \begin{branch}
      \item i am a cat
    \newleaf
      \item i can change color
      \item i am a lizard
  \end{branch}
  \begin{branch}
      \item i am a frog
      \item i can fly
    \newleaf
      \item i am a gizzard
  \end{branch}
    \item i am an animal
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It's slightly more OTT than I expected, mainly because `\setcounter` doesn't set counters globally and we need to set the value of the `enumi` counter at the end.

The `branch` environment accepts an optional argument for specifying the number of columns/leaves (so use `\begin{branch}{3}` for three columns). Needless to say you shouldn't have more leaves than columns -- I didn't add a check for this but `multicols` will complain.

If required, you can fine-tune the spacing using the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. See the manual for details.